# LPAD function in triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment, oracle12c

I just create triggers for SQL which autoincrement primary key. It works but I want to have ID with the prefix (0001,0002...9999). I found that I should use LPAD but every time I tried to use, it shows errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_PRIMARY_KEY
BEFORE INSERT ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    SELECT produkt_sequence.nextval
    into :new.id_product 
    from dual;
END;
```

Comment: if you want your  `id` with prefix `000` ..then the `id` should be of type `varchar2` and not `number` ...

Comment: How are you trying to use `lpad`, and what errors does it give you? You could also use `to_char()`. Are you sure you really want your ID to be stored as a string though - rather than as a number that can be padded when queried if necessary, or with a virtual column that's separate from the PK - and limited to four digits?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for help! The problem was of type. I had a number. If I want to use LPAD, it must be varchar2. Thank you again.